# Prove that $\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm{d}x = \frac{b-a}2 [f(a)+f(b)]+\frac12 \int_a^b (x-a)(x-b)f''(x)\mathrm{d}x\,.$

Tags: calculus

> Prove that $$\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm{d}x = \frac{b-a}2 [f(a)+f(b)]+\frac12 \int_a^b (x-a)(x-b)f''(x)\mathrm{d}x\,.$$

Given that $f(x)$ is continuous within $[a, b]$，how can I proof the above equation holds ?
I tried using Taylor's formula to replace $f(x)$ on the right side of the equation:
$$
f(x) = f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac12 f''(\xi_1)(x-a)^2\\
f(x) = f(b)+f'(b)(x-b)+\frac12 f''(\xi_1)(x-b)^2
$$
therefore
\begin{align}
\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm dx=&\frac{b-a}2[f(a)+f(b)]+\frac12 f'(a)\int_a^b (x-a)\mathrm dx+\frac12 f'(b)\int_a^b (x-b)\mathrm dx\\
&+\frac14 f''(\xi_1)\int_a^b(x-a)^2\mathrm dx+\frac14 f''(\xi_2)\int_a^b(x-b)^2\mathrm dx
\end{align}
but this will not get the desired result.

Comment: Perhaps integration by parts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is nice but unfortunately will not work as $\xi$ is not a fixed value in Taylor’s formula.

Instead consider starting from the integral to the very right and applying partial integration twice…